# How to fix error: User cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default"?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-cluster

I've got a problem with roles and authentication kubernetes. I created a one-node (one maser) cluster, on my baremetal server, and I made this cluster listen on different IP than default (with option "*--apiserver-advertise-address=* *ip address* "). But now I basically can do nothing in it, because of *kubectl* does not work. I can't create pods and services I need. When I created the cluster, without this IP changinh, it works. So my question  is how to fix this? It is probably an authorization problem, but I can't even create cluster role or cluster role binding because of errors like this: *" error: failed to create clusterrolebinding: clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:node:e4-1" cannot create resource "clusterrolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope"*... Is there any way to "login" as admin, or something, or is there a way to change something in configs files to fix this?

Comment: It appears that you are using wrong config file. Instead of `kubelet.conf` you should be using `admin.conf`. Both located in `/etc/kubernetes`. Can you verify that please?

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the flag you mention I assume you are using `kubeadm` to create your cluster. Most probable cause is that you are using the wrong `.conf` file. My suspicions are that you are using the `kubelet.conf` instead of `admin.conf`.

Below you can find an example of the `kubeadm init` output. It contains steps that you need to follow to start using `kubectl`:

```
Your Kubernetes control-plane has initialized successfully!

To start using your cluster, you need to run the following as a regular user:

  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

You should now deploy a Pod network to the cluster.
Run "kubectl apply -f [podnetwork].yaml" with one of the options listed at:
  /docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/

You can now join any number of machines by running the following on each node
as root:

  kubeadm join <control-plane-host>:<control-plane-port> --token <token> --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:<hash>
```

As you see one of the commands is to copy `admin.conf` file into `/.kube/config` which then `kubectl` uses to manage cluster.